# How to set cursor position in CodeMirror in accordance to cursor position in TinyMCE 5?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, codemirror

I have a form on the webpage, which uses `TinyMCE 5` to edit one of the fields. In my configuration, the `TinyMCE` uses `CodeMirror` in order to inspect/edit the html-code of the field's content. When the `CodeMirror` starts, it positions the cursor at the beginning of the code, but I would like to find a way how to set initial cursor position in `CodeMirror` to the place in html-code, which corresponds to the position of cursor in `TinyMCE`. In other words, if the cursor is located e.g. inside a table in `TinyMCE` when I call the `CodeMirror` (by pressing "code" button on menu panel), I would like the `CodeMirror` to set its cursor close to or inside the `<table>` tag in the html-code.

The solution, which comes to my mind, is to get the tag name at the cursor position in `TinyMCE`, then start `CodeMirror`, find the line in `CodeMirror`, which contains that tag, and finally position the cursor to that line. But I don't really understand how to implement this. Should I edit the `codemirror/plugin.js` or there is another less destructive way?

Any ideas are welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some research I've found the answer to my question. I hope it will be helpful for someone else.

First of all, the functionality described in my question has already been implemented in the `CodeMirror`. It's controlled by the `CodeMirror` option `saveCursorPosition`. If it's set to `true`, `CodeMirror` positions cursor to the place in the html-code, which corresponds to the position of the cursor in the `TinyMCE` editor and vice versa.

But the most funny thing is that all of the above doesn't work :) In order to save the cursor position, the `tinymce-codemirror` plugin adds the invisible `span` to the html-code of the `TinyMCE` content (`<span style="display: none;" class="CmCaReT">&#x0;</span>`). Just before the `CodeMirror` instance is activated, the plugin replaces that span with invisible character (UTF code = 0), otherwise the `span` tag would be visible in the `CodeMirror`.

This replacement is performed by the following code (in the `source.html` file located at the same folder as `plugin.js` and `plugin.min.js`): `html.replace(/<span\s+style="display: none;"\s+class="CmCaReT"([^>]*)>([^<]*)<\/span>/gm, String.fromCharCode(chr))`. The regular expression should find all those `span`-s, but it doesn't! The reason is that `style` and `class` attributes appear to be in opposite order: the `class` is the first, then follows the `style`. (I think this is the surprise made by the browser - I use Firefox.)

Now, we have to change the regular expression to `/<span\s+(style="display: none;")*\s*(class="CmCaReT")\s+(style="display: none;")*([^>]*)>([^<]*)<\/span>/gm` , which catches the `span` tag regardless of the order of its attributes.

So, now jumping between corresponding positions in TinyMCE and CodeMirror works fine!